# Create table in multiple databases with flyway

Tags: flyway

I'm trying to connect to the multiple databases and create tables, but when migrating flyway gets syntax error.

This is the migration file I'm trying to run:

```
\c testdatabase;
CREATE TABLE testtable1;

\c testdatabase2;
CREATE TABLE testtable2;
```

Flyway gives this output:

```
Error Code : 0
Message : ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
Position: 1
Line : 1
Statement : \c testdatabase
```

It seems like flyway does not support meta-commands like "\c" for connecting to the database. Is there any other way to do connect to the databases and create a table?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes (as indicated in the error input) from the comment lines preceding your two SQL statements in the script: `\c testdatabase;` which are not valid SQL syntax for comments.

You could simply correct those faulty lines like the following: `-- testdatabase`, and generally, the error input already gives you a hint as to where lies the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to the databases and create a table. It seems like flyway does not support meta-commands like "\c" for connecting to the database.

Comment: You should feed Flyway with the necessary data to connect to the database via the configuration, not the script. The script describe a step in the DB schema migration, it is not meant to handle the DB configuration, users and such.